# Give hyperlink to TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in that i am using

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last name">
          <ItemTemplate>
             <%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Profile.LastName %>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to give a hyperlink to Last Name and on clicking on that I want to open a <strike>ascx</strike> aspx page base on the Last Name. How to do that please someone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last name">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <a href="lastname.aspx?lname=<%#((User)Container.DataItem).Profile.LastName %>">
                     <%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Profile.LastName %>
                 </a>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

then in your lastname.aspx you can react on the querystring like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string lastname= Request.QueryString["lname"];

    //do stuff
}
```